# Differences between Internet Explorer and others on buttons and input field, what is submitted in a form?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, standards, spring-webflow

Id like to ask why Internet Explorer in the following example submits the button which is of type button in the parameter list when the submit button is pushed? While Firefox doesnt.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Button test page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="/whatever" method="GET">
<div align="center">
<br><br>
<input type="hidden" value="hey" name="hidden_greeting">
<button type="button" size="35" value="lolie" name="btb">button_type_button</button>
<button type="submit" value="sb" name="ssb">submit</button>
<br><br>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what is submitted when using IE, ?hidden_greeting=hey&btb=button_type_button&ssb=submit and this is when using Firefox ?hidden_greeting=hey&ssb=sb

Why is this? This causes problems with Spring Webflow because it checks only the name for eventIds and then it performs the wrong action because the IE browser submitted in the parameter list the button of type button name and its innerHTML as value even though the button of type submit was only pressed.

What is the good thing to do here in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Form Tags should solve your problem.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/spring-form.tld.html